# Form Not Closing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, stream

When I close my form I want to write somo data to a text file, I have this:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter archivo = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Marcelo\Documents\Proyectos\database.txt");
    for (int i = 1; i <=10 ; i++)
    {
        archivo.Write(nombres[i] + " " + temp[i] + " " + cap[i]);
        if (i != nseries)
            archivo.Write("\r\n"); 
    }
    archivo.Close();
}
```

But when I click the close button it doesn't work, I have to click it multiple times.
What's wrong?

**EDIT:** It gets me this exception: "The process cannot gain access to the file '...', because is being utilized by other process (rough translation) ¿How do I fix it?

**FINAL EDIT:** I Figured ir out, other method in my aplication was not closing the program after writing in it, thank you very much all for your kind help

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line. Does it even enter the block?

Comment: Are you sure you have to click it multiple times?  Are you sure you're not just being impatient?  Try clicking it once, does it work?  It might freeze for a second while it's writing to the file.

Comment: Do you see a "first chance exception" notification in the Output window?  Using the 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: @HansPassant is right, an exception thrown in the Closing event actually aborts the closing so the window stays open.

Comment: As a side point, I wouldn't run this code (saving settings to a file) in the Closing event of the form.  This would cause an unresponsive UI if it takes too long for any reason (hard drive asleep?  really big file?).  This logic should probably go outside of the form message loop, so after the `Application.Run` method in your `Program.cs` folder if you're using the default Winforms conventions.  This way your window would close right away but the process would stay running however long it needs to.

Comment: try to use Form1_FormClosed instead of Form1_FormClosing

Comment: Sometime it throws me an "Stack Overflow" exception

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check the event of form closing in the designer, the **code behind** `(Form1_FormClosing)` **and the designer** mode event's name **are equal**?

Please **put a break point** into you code behind too.

Please use **Try-Catch** in your event:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        StreamWriter archivo = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Marcelo\Documents\Proyectos\database.txt");
        for (int i = 1; i <=10 ; i++)
        {
            archivo.Write(nombres[i] + " " + temp[i] + " " + cap[i]);
            if (i != nseries)
                archivo.Write("\r\n"); 

        }
        archivo.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        //MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use textwriter instead and wrap it inside a using block. The problem I can see with your code is

For Loop:

```
 archivo.Write(nombres[i] + " " + temp[i] + " " + cap[i]);
        if (i != nseries)
            archivo.Write("\r\n");
```

End Loop:

Generally Write methods are not preferred to call under loop. Instead it is preferred to build you desired output inside a loop and flush that text to file in one go. See the code below:

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("C:\\perl.txt"))
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 1; i <=10 ; i++)
   {
     sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2},nombres[i],temp[i],cap[i]);
   }
  writer.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```